# Modeling as AR or MA according to these results and checking stationarity

Tags: time-series, arima, modeling, aic

I need to classify a process into AR or MA, because this determines if I can use some expressions in a future chemical analysis.

To this end I sampled the variable of interest and used [statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html) with differents p, d, q values for fitting ARIMA(p,d,q) models, and extracted the Akaike information criterion (AIC) value.

```
p  d  q  AIC  
0, 0, 1, 345368
0, 0, 2, 289863
0, 1, 1, 190172
0, 1, 2, 189956
0, 2, 1, 196621
1, 0, 0, 192536
1, 0, 1, 187833
1, 0, 2, 187777
1, 1, 0, 190929
1, 1, 1, 189890
1, 1, 2, 187842
1, 2, 0, 256829
2, 0, 0, 188227
2, 0, 1, 187772
2, 0, 2, 187767
2, 1, 0, 190215
2, 1, 1, 188234
2, 1, 2, 187840
2, 2, 0, 236290
```

I have zero experience or formation on this subject. My intuition suggest me that:

- The process fits well into AR(1) classification.  The coefficient is very close to 1.0 and because of this (0, 1, 0) also works fine.
- The process is not of MA, and (0, 1, 1) do not indicate non-stationarity of the series.

I wish to know if my reasoning is correct or incorrect. If it is incorrect, why and which kind of model is it? If nothing can be concluded from this data, what can I do for classifying the process?

*Additional information*:

- The times series correspond to the mean direction of particles at different times.
- The sample vector has 125000 elements.
- I won't do forecasting.
- The parameters (constant/coefficient) for (1,0,0) are (-0.0008, 0.9364). For (1,0,1):  (-0.0009, 0.9616, -0.2136).

**EDIT:**
If it is important, the normalized autocorrelation function of the series behaves like $e^{-|a|t}$

**EDIT 2:**
I uploaded the data.  As original time series is extremely large, for storage issues, I uploaded just a fraction of it. However, it should be much more larger than needed for all purposes.

http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1522088203837.txt

Plot of variable vs time.

[image: https://ibb.co/ce86LS]

Plot of the autocorrelation function

[image: https://ibb.co/dLgRLS]

Comment: Is time increment a constant? Can you show us a plot of the series, and of its acf? and possibly share a link to the data?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for comment. Yes, time increment is a constant. I can show you the plots and share the data. I'll upload that info. in minutes.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I edited the question adding links to the requested information.

Comment: you can't compare ICs of differences and nondifferences series

Comment: @Aksakal, Thanks for answering. Are you saying that I can only use AIC for (p, 0, d)?

Comment: see #4 in Hyndman's post [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/aic/)

Comment: @Aksakal , I think I understand you, sample is discrete so differencing 1 time (d=1) leaves out 1 value. Is that significant in practical terms due to  this sample has thousands of observations?

Comment: I haven't thought about it this way, but in practice you first decide whether to difference or not, then compare AIC within what you decided.

Comment: It's not just that you lose one data point by differencing - you are changing all the values in the dataset. You also cannot compare models fit to transformed and untransformed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked a little at the time series.  Summary of conclusions: original series is not stationary, but differenced series is stationary. There is no real uncertainty.  The autocorrelation function of the differenced series looks like an autogressive series, and a arima(1,1,0) model seems to fit well. For some reason automatic model selection prefers not to difference (based on KPSS test), but I doubt that!

I did analysis in R and will give some code here. First reading the posted data:

```
X  <-  read.table("long_time_series.txt")
X  <-  X$V1
X <- as.ts(X)

dX  <-  diff(X)
```

I will plot the data, and to study possible nonstationarity I will overlay a simple smooth:

```
plot(X)
lines( lowess(time(X), X, 1/100), col="red")
```

[image]

You can see the local mean (in red) moving up and down, the series is not stationary. No hypothesis test is necessary! This up-and down movements is what causes the slow decay of the autocorrelation function of the series (not shown).

We do the same for the differenced series:

```
plot(dX)
lines( lowess(time(dX), dX, 1/100), col="red")
```

[image]

and now the local mean is pretty constant, so this differened series *is* stationary. Its autocorrelation function is also quite simple:

```
acf(dX, lag.max=20)
```

[image]

and this looks like an ar(1) model could fit:

```
> mod1  <-  arima(X, order=c(1, 1, 0))
> summary(mod1)

Call:
arima(x = X, order = c(1, 1, 0))

Coefficients:
          ar1
      -0.2101
s.e.   0.0028

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2697:  log likelihood = -95461.78,  aic = 190927.6

Training set error measures:
                        ME      RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -2.551876e-05 0.5193162 0.4142524 -164.122 394.1604 0.9777882
                   ACF1
Training set -0.0158746
```

Some diagnostics:

```
tsdiag(mod1)
```

[image]

The autocorrelation function is quite close to that of white noise, but the small deviation is significant due to huge sample size. If a more complex model will be useful is doubtful, but let us see hat auto.arima thinks:

```
library(forecast)
auto.arima(X, max.p=10, max.q=10, D=0, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE, parallel=TRUE, trace=TRUE)

Series: X 
ARIMA(3,0,1) with zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3      ma1
      1.1782  -0.1822  -0.0231  -0.4259
s.e.  0.0385   0.0287   0.0086   0.0384

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2629:  log likelihood=-93877.74
AIC=187765.5   AICc=187765.5   BIC=187814.2
```

so this prefers not to difference, based on `kpss.test` (in package `tseries`). Let us force differencing:

```
 auto.arima(X, max.p=10, max.q=10, d=1, D=0, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE, parallel=TRUE, trace=TRUE)


Series: X 
ARIMA(0,1,5) 

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2      ma3      ma4      ma5
      -0.2322  -0.0369  -0.0237  -0.0200  -0.0165
s.e.   0.0028   0.0029   0.0030   0.0029   0.0029

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2672:  log likelihood=-94878.14
AIC=189768.3   AICc=189768.3   BIC=189826.7
```

and---surprise--- this chooses an arima(0,1,5) model. But note that the estimated variances are very close. And, knowing that an ar(1) model can be represented as $\text{ma}(\infty)$, they should be pretty close. You could compare the residuals!

I am not sure of the reason behind the discrepancy of my manual analysis and auto.arima.  Before using the results I would compare models for differenced and original data with some sort of cross validation, maybe first estimating models on first half of data, then using them for prediction on second half. I think that would give a better ground for model choice, but I leave that to you.